# IE10 scales images differently than Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

For an assignment I need to write about why various things work differently on my website when it comes to viewing it in different browsers. One of the differences I've found is that in IE10 where I made images smaller to fit on the page, IE ignores that and only scales the image with Width: %; Here is the code for the image:

```
<img class="image" src="images/tcp-ip layers.gif" />

.image {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #E5E4E2;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Does anyone know why IE doesn't scale down the image like Firefox would?
Edit: it works the same in Firefox as it does in Chrome, It's not good code I agree, I should of used auto's etc. But I just need to figure out why it resizes it differently in Firefox. (if anything IE10 resizes it better but its too late to make the amendments I should of)

Comment: Provide the whole code pls, because your code should not work correctly in any browser. Ofc maybe it just happens to be firefox who interprets it that way that you think ots right.

Answer (score 1):

Image scaling using bicubic interpolation is turned **off** in IE per default, every other browser has that **on** by default. Try to fix this with:

```
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```